# Spell check function?

Tags: cognito-forms

Does anyone know if there's a spell check feature for forms?

I can't seem to find this option anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I work on the Cognito Forms Team.
No currently there is not a spell check feature in Cognito Forms.

Looking through our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/b/ZS1698De/idea-board) I didn't see where that feature had been requested yet. 
I suspect there are 2 primary reasons why folks have not asked for a spell-check feature.

1. Many modern day browsers will have a spell-check feature built in that highlights misspelled words
2. Often when people are placing a block of content into Cognito Forms they are just cutting and pasting the content from a word processing program that has already been spell-checked

Although I don't recall hearing of a feature request for a Spell-check feature you can certainly go to our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/b/ZS1698De/idea-board) and add it if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers come with Spell checkers built in, If not you can always use one of the many websites that checks it for you before publishing it.

I like using this one as it supports US and UK spelling of words.

http://www.reverso.net/spell-checker/english-spelling-grammar/